# How to wait App.js code to run before mounting components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a problem, where I use a piece of code in App.js to sign the user in, if they have a JWT token stored (to keep them signed in if they leave the page, then return). I am using socket.io to communicate with the server.

The problem is, in a component of mine I make a socket.io call inside componentDidMount(), but that code runs before the App.js code, therefore the socket is not yet stored in my backend. The way the application is now, I am storing the socketIDs and userIDs of users to keep track of open sockets per user.

If the componentDidMount() code runs before storing the newly created socket connection (on opening a new tab, a new socket is created) I can't use the new socket in that call.

I logged the functions to see the order, and this is what I got, that's why I suspect the componentDidMount() code runs first.

```js
userID empty null
usersOfCall null
socketAssign
[
  {
    userID: '5fb483cf93b92d651a281450',
    socketIDs: [ 'hdLMOfFhFXHGyOpDAAAB' ],
    socketPreserved: null
  },
  {
    userID: '5fb47647c93e23622c4e1c10',
    socketIDs: [ 'JAcC2XwLuoZTsgIiAAAC', '7vgKN-sqkqUNS7L_AAAD' ],
    socketPreserved: null
  }
]
```

From the `socketAssign` line below, that is where I store the socket for a user.
Above that is the result of the call I make from inside `componentDidMount()`
The `userID empty null` line is the result of a function that would get the userID of the user associated with the socket that emitted the signal. It becomes null, since the socket is not yet stored, so it can't find any matches.

App.js piece of code:

```js
if(localStorage.jwtToken){
    const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
    const tokenDecoded = jwt_decode(token);
    const user = tokenDecoded.response;
    store.dispatch(userSocketAssign(user));
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
    if(tokenDecoded.exp < currentTime){
        console.log('expired');
        store.dispatch(userSocketDeassign());
        window.location.href = './login';
    }
}

function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store = {store}>
            <AppComponent />
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

The AppComponent just renders the routes for the application, with component properties that specify which component should be rendered when a specific route is taken.

```js
class App extends Component
{
    componentDidMount(){
        
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Router>
                <Navbar />
                <Switch className = "container-fluid">
                    <Route exact path = "/" component = {Dashboard} />
                    <Route exact path = "/login" component = {Login} />
                    ...
                </Switch>
                <CallReceived />
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

How could I make the mount process wait until the socket is stored on the backend?

Comment: Just use conditional rendering for the entire `<Router>` part. `{this.state.hasLoaded && <Router>...</Router>}`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read about the state cycle. Based on your situation, you can set a timer for the component to run. Inside the component, try add setInterval for the delay for the app to render first. Here is the documentation about the state cycle https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.

Comment: Using a timer to wait for an API reply is bad practice and not necessary anyway (unless it's about implementing a custom timeout for the API request)